# How can I transfer a binary file using minicom and a serial connection?

Tags: command-line, files, serial-port

How can I transfer a binary file using a serial cable between my Ubuntu pc and a box where I've installed minicom? The minicom box doesn't have a connection.

Comment: Is a serial cable the only option? Does the box have a network card? A usb port?

Comment: yes @ terdon , the serial cable the only option .it haven't a network card , usb port.

Comment: Did you read  http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=Serial_Transfer

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this before, but [this](http://k.japko.eu/serial-transfers.html) page says you can send binary via minicom by encoding it in ASCII. You need to have `busybox` installed on the box.

Use `uuencode` to encode. Here is it's syntax:

```
uuencode [INFILE] STORED_FILENAME > send_file
```

INFILE is the path to file to encode and STORED_FILENAME is obviously the name of the file. uuencode outputs to stdout, so it is redirected to a temporary file, `send_file`.

Ready the target machine for recieving file:

```
target$ cat > recieved_file
```

Now it is uploaded as ascii using minicom:

```
host$ minicom
CTRL+A S
+-[Upload]--+                                                
| zmodem    |                                                     
| ymodem    |                                                
| xmodem    |                                                
| kermit    |                                                
|>ascii<    |                                                
+-----------+
```

On the target, decode the file:

```
uudecode [-o OUTFILE] [INFILE]
```

To see if it worked as expected, check md5:

```
busybox md5sum <filename>
```

Please see if this works and post back, because I have never done this. myself

Comment: FYI: Just tried it on Ubuntu and Petalinux and it worked perfectly!

Comment: And how do you send byte-for-byte binary if the embedded system does not permit you decode ascii?